# DatePicker look and feel

Tags: android, datepicker, android-layout

Hi i've a HTC Desire and want a date pciker to look like the spinning wheels in the datepicker i see in the agenda etc. If i use this code

```
 return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

I always see the default datepicker with up and down buttons without the swipe to spin the wheels. Is there a sample of how to use these

Greetings Andre Mens

Comment: HTC are using custom DatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually modifying the built in DatePicker and compiling your own build of Android, you're going to need to use a third party solution. This may (or may not) work for you -

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/